# Delayed execution for 'Explain' queries on Prestosql clusters

Tags: trino, hive-metastore

I have two types of prestosql clusters, on aws instances and on Kubernetes. Prestosql on K8s has a weird issue with 'EXPLAIN' queries as it takes a long time ~2-3 mins compared to 2-3 seconds on the instance one.

The query stays on "WAITING_FOR_RESOURCES" for about 2 minutes and then executes very quickly.
There is also an exception on the server logs

```
2020-12-23T05:25:01.930Z    ERROR   Query-20201223_052431_00004_pxqak-276   io.prestosql.cost.CachingStatsProvider  Error occurred when computing stats for query 20201223_052431_00004_pxqak
io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getMetastorePartitionColumnStatistics(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:461)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getPartitionColumnStatistics(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:438)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getPartitionStatistics(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:389)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.BridgingHiveMetastore.getPartitionStatistics(BridgingHiveMetastore.java:110)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.lambda$loadPartitionColumnStatistics$6(CachingHiveMetastore.java:360)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.loadPartitionColumnStatistics(CachingHiveMetastore.java:353)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.access$100(CachingHiveMetastore.java:89)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore$1.loadAll(CachingHiveMetastore.java:179)
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$1.loadAll(CacheLoader.java:207)
    at io.prestosql.cost.JoinStatsRule.doCalculate(JoinStatsRule.java:81)
    at io.prestosql.cost.JoinStatsRule.doCalculate(JoinStatsRule.java:48)
    at io.prestosql.cost.SimpleStatsRule.calculate(SimpleStatsRule.java:39)
    at io.prestosql.cost.ComposableStatsCalculator.calculateStats(ComposableStatsCalculator.java:82)
    at io.prestosql.cost.ComposableStatsCalculator.calculateStats(ComposableStatsCalculator.java:70)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CachingStatsProvider.getGroupStats(CachingStatsProvider.java:103)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CachingStatsProvider.getStats(CachingStatsProvider.java:72)
    at io.prestosql.cost.JoinStatsRule.doCalculate(JoinStatsRule.java:81)
    at io.prestosql.cost.JoinStatsRule.doCalculate(JoinStatsRule.java:48)
    at io.prestosql.cost.SimpleStatsRule.calculate(SimpleStatsRule.java:39)
    at io.prestosql.cost.ComposableStatsCalculator.calculateStats(ComposableStatsCalculator.java:82)
    at io.prestosql.cost.ComposableStatsCalculator.calculateStats(ComposableStatsCalculator.java:70)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CachingStatsProvider.getGroupStats(CachingStatsProvider.java:103)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CachingStatsProvider.getStats(CachingStatsProvider.java:72)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CostCalculatorWithEstimatedExchanges.calculateJoinExchangeCost(CostCalculatorWithEstimatedExchanges.java:233)
    at io.prestosql.cost.CostCalculatorWithEstimatedExchanges.calculateJoinCostWithoutOutput(CostCalculatorWithEstimatedExchanges.java:208)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.rule.DetermineJoinDistributionType.getJoinNodeWithCost(DetermineJoinDistributionType.java:180)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.rule.DetermineJoinDistributionType.addJoinsWithDifferentDistributions(DetermineJoinDistributionType.java:116)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.rule.DetermineJoinDistributionType.getCostBasedJoin(DetermineJoinDistributionType.java:98)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.rule.DetermineJoinDistributionType.apply(DetermineJoinDistributionType.java:74)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.rule.DetermineJoinDistributionType.apply(DetermineJoinDistributionType.java:49)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.transform(IterativeOptimizer.java:165)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreNode(IterativeOptimizer.java:140)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:105)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreChildren(IterativeOptimizer.java:190)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.loadAll(LocalCache.java:4058)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getAll(LocalCache.java:4021)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getAll(LocalCache.java:4972)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getAll(CachingHiveMetastore.java:255)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getPartitionStatistics(CachingHiveMetastore.java:330)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.lambda$loadPartitionColumnStatistics$6(CachingHiveMetastore.java:360)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.loadPartitionColumnStatistics(CachingHiveMetastore.java:353)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.access$100(CachingHiveMetastore.java:89)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore$1.loadAll(CachingHiveMetastore.java:179)
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$1.loadAll(CacheLoader.java:207)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.loadAll(LocalCache.java:4058)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getAll(LocalCache.java:4021)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getAll(LocalCache.java:4972)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getAll(CachingHiveMetastore.java:255)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.cache.CachingHiveMetastore.getPartitionStatistics(CachingHiveMetastore.java:330)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveMetastoreClosure.getPartitionStatistics(HiveMetastoreClosure.java:88)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.getPartitionStatistics(SemiTransactionalHiveMetastore.java:256)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.statistics.MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.getPartitionsStatistics(MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.java:126)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.statistics.MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.lambda$new$0(MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.java:104)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.statistics.MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.getTableStatistics(MetastoreHiveStatisticsProvider.java:146)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.getTableStatistics(HiveMetadata.java:695)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:107)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreChildren(IterativeOptimizer.java:190)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:107)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.optimize(IterativeOptimizer.java:96)
    at io.prestosql.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.plan(LogicalPlanner.java:196)
    at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.QueryExplainer.getLogicalPlan(QueryExplainer.java:182)
    at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.QueryExplainer.getPlan(QueryExplainer.java:121)
    at io.prestosql.sql.rewrite.ExplainRewrite$Visitor.getQueryPlan(ExplainRewrite.java:137)
    at io.prestosql.sql.rewrite.ExplainRewrite$Visitor.visitExplain(ExplainRewrite.java:115)
    at io.prestosql.sql.rewrite.ExplainRewrite$Visitor.visitExplain(ExplainRewrite.java:65)
    at io.prestosql.sql.tree.Explain.accept(Explain.java:80)
    at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
    at io.prestosql.sql.rewrite.ExplainRewrite.rewrite(ExplainRewrite.java:62)
    at io.prestosql.sql.rewrite.StatementRewrite.rewrite(StatementRewrite.java:57)
    at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:80)
    at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:75)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyze(SqlQueryExecution.java:221)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.<init>(SqlQueryExecution.java:180)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.<init>(SqlQueryExecution.java:97)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution$SqlQueryExecutionFactory.createQueryExecution(SqlQueryExecution.java:732)
    at io.prestosql.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQueryFactory.lambda$createDispatchQuery$0(LocalDispatchQueryFactory.java:119)
    at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_330____20201223_050837_2.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: MetaException(message:null)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_statistics_req_result$get_partitions_statistics_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_statistics_req_result$get_partitions_statistics_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_statistics_req_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_partitions_statistics_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_partitions_statistics_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4000)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.getPartitionColumnStatistics(ThriftHiveMetastoreClient.java:227)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.lambda$getPartitionColumnStatistics$16(FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.java:191)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.runWithHandle(FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.java:394)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.getPartitionColumnStatistics(FailureAwareThriftMetastoreClient.java:191)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.lambda$getMetastorePartitionColumnStatistics$15(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:453)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftMetastoreApiStats.lambda$wrap$0(ThriftMetastoreApiStats.java:42)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.util.RetryDriver.run(RetryDriver.java:130)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastore.getMetastorePartitionColumnStatistics(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:451)
    ... 156 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
    Suppressed: MetaException(message:null)
        ... 170 more
```

I tried changing the values of `hive.metastore.partition-batch-size.max` and `hive.metastore-cache-ttl`

Answer (score 0):

It seems than in your "slow" deployment the metastore call `get_partitions_statistics_req` fails for some reason and is getting retried. The retries likely consume all the "waiting" time. Since Presto by default ignores stats calculation failures like this, the query eventually works.

The failure is on the Hive side, so you need to check metastore logs to understand the cause of the failure, since it's not getting propagated on the Presto side.

On the Presto side you can still apply some configuration changes, as a workaround:

- disable stats for the Hive connector with `hive.table-statistics-enabled` configuration property
- reduce the time spent retrying metastore calls with `hive.metastore.thrift.client.max-retry-time` configuration property
- make your queries fail loud with global config property `optimizer.ignore-stats-calculator-failures=false` (unlikely what you want)